# How do you prepare/cook Kohl Rabi?

Tags: kohlrabi

I regularly get an organic veg box, which occasionally contains items that I'm less familiar with, or are more challenging to make something delicious with. One that causes me a lot of trouble is Kohl Rabi, as it's not something I've come across, so don't know the best ways to prepare it. So, what is the best way to eat Kohl Rabi?